# jQuery and PHP, working with arrays

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui-sortable, flat-file

I'd like to post the order of my thumbnails to a text file as an array to be read and echoed by some *PHP* later. The current `file()` function in *PHP* looks for a character return to signal each array entry.

***jQuery:***

```
var order = $('#thumbList').sortable('toArray');
```

***PHP:***

```
$order=file('order.txt');
 foreach ($order as $value) {
    echo "<img src='gal/img/sml/$value' />";
}
```

I'm wondering what the best way would be to go about saving and reading an array between *jQuery* and *PHP* so that I wouldn't have to reformat the array for each language.

Comment: The current array returned by the .sortable() function looks something like: ["image_1.jpg","image_2.jpg","image_3.jpg"]

Answer (score 1):

Could you serialize it to [JSON](http://json.org/)? PHP and Javascript (JS only with an additional library) are both able to handle it.